# viewpager call only 2 oncreateview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

i have 4 Fragments in viewpager
but if i get into activity that have viewpager
[only 2 fragments call oncreateview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGfR8.png)

so remain fragments cant call their component and occurs null pointer error

i have pageradapter and i didnt call them separately

how can i fix this?

**--- pageradapter ---**

```
public class SearchPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public SearchPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragmentManager = fm;
        arrayList.add(new SearchPageBookFragment());
        arrayList.add(new SearchPageFeedFragment());
        arrayList.add(new SearchPageChallengeFragment());
        arrayList.add(new SearchPageUserFragment());
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
}
```

**--- connect viewpager and fragments ---**

```
  searchPageBookFragment = ((SearchPageBookFragment) ((SearchPageAdapter) binding.viewpager.getAdapter()).getItem(0));
 
  searchPageFeedFragment = ((SearchPageFeedFragment) ((SearchPageAdapter) binding.viewpager.getAdapter()).getItem(1));
 
  searchPageChallengeFragment = ((SearchPageChallengeFragment) ((SearchPageAdapter) binding.viewpager.getAdapter()).getItem(2));

  searchPageUserFragment = ((SearchPageUserFragment) ((SearchPageAdapter) binding.viewpager.getAdapter()).getItem(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

change viewpager offscreenPageLimit to below

```
binding.viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
```

it will initialise all fragment.